# Error phoenix app sending Email on fly.io with Resend

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, fly, resend.com

I am building my company’s website, so I decided to use Resend for mailing.

Locally. All works fine, but when I put my website on production, the Resend API doesn’t work, and sentry shows me the error below.

mi config is:
elixir Version:1.15.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 26)
Phoenix: 1.7.7
resend: 0.4

`no match of right-hand side value: {: error, :enoent}`

`pubkey_os_cacerts.erl in :pubkey_os_cacerts.get/0 at line 38`
`httpc.erl in :httpc.ssl_verify_host_options/1 at line 476`
`httpc.erl in anonymous fn/0 in :httpc.http_options_default/0 at line 1015`
`httpc.erl in :httpc.http_options/3 at line 961`
`httpc.erl in :httpc.handle_request/9 at line 771`
`lib/tesla/adapter/httpc.ex in Tesla.Adapter.Httpc.request/2 at line 52`
`lib/tesla/adapter/httpc.ex in Tesla.Adapter.Httpc.call/2 at line 22`
`lib/tesla/middleware/json.ex in Tesla.Middleware.JSON.call/3 at line 54`

I need to send a email,
locally works and change from swoosh to a simple Resend apis with POST method
but locally continue working and in production continue failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [this issue reported on the otp](https://github.com/erlang/otp/issues/7295), and from what the error message says, your production machine is missing its root cert file. The error is described [here in the OTP documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/public_key#cacerts_get-0).

> Returns the trusted CA certificates if any are loaded, otherwise uses cacerts_load/0 to load them. The function fails if no cacerts could be loaded.

You need to install a CA certificate on the machine.

Comment: How can I do that? on fly.io

Comment: https://fly.io/docs/app-guides/custom-domains-with-fly/